# How to graph Google OR Tools Vehicle Routing Problem Solution?

Tags: python, matplotlib, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am using Google OR tools to solve a simple vehicle routing problem in Python. I want to plot the solution that the solver returns in the way similar to the Google tutorial:
[Google OR Tools Vehicle Routing Problem Tutorial Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojp9R.png)

This is the code I'm using from the tutorial:

```
def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
"""Prints solution on console."""
max_route_distance = 0
for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
    plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
    route_distance = 0
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
        plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        previous_index = index
        index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
            previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
    plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
    plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
    print(plan_output)
    max_route_distance = max(route_distance, max_route_distance)
print('Maximum of the route distances: {}m'.format(max_route_distance))
```

and this is the solution I am getting:

Route for vehicle 0:
0 ->  93 ->  92 ->  91 ->  53 ->  56 ->  52 ->  51 ->  61 ->  62 ->  63 ->  64 ->  65 ->  68 ->  67 ->  66 ->  70 ->  69 ->  100 ->  99 ->  98 ->  97 ->  96 ->  94 ->  95 -> 0
Distance of the route: 530m

Route for vehicle 1:
0 ->  4 ->  5 ->  10 ->  9 ->  90 ->  89 ->  83 ->  82 ->  81 ->  87 ->  41 ->  44 ->  47 ->  49 ->  50 ->  14 ->  17 ->  19 ->  18 ->  20 ->  22 ->  23 ->  26 ->  31 ->  33 -> 0
Distance of the route: 621m

Route for vehicle 2:
0 ->  1 ->  2 ->  7 ->  8 ->  86 ->  88 ->  85 ->  84 ->  59 ->  60 ->  79 ->  76 ->  77 ->  74 ->  71 ->  72 ->  73 ->  75 ->  78 ->  80 ->  58 ->  57 ->  55 ->  54 -> 0
Distance of the route: 614m

Route for vehicle 3:
0 ->  3 ->  6 ->  43 ->  42 ->  46 ->  45 ->  48 ->  11 ->  12 ->  15 ->  13 ->  16 ->  25 ->  27 ->  29 ->  28 ->  30 ->  35 ->  36 ->  40 ->  37 ->  39 ->  38 ->  34 ->  32 ->  24 ->  21 -> 0
Distance of the route: 620m

How can I plot this solution similar to the image?

Answer (score 1):

This image is a generated svg using a python script.
You can find the source here:
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/docs/routing_svg.py

which is call by the shell script:
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/docs/generate_svg.sh

ps: Don't hesitate to ask on our discord (link in the project README.md) for further details...

Comment: Thank you! But my vrp problem has no constraints except number of vehicles = 4, should I just make all the other constraints in the data model like time windows and capacity as 0? @Mizux

Answer (score 0):

It is using the program here:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/cvrptw_plot.py